# Remove existing sibling with the same class, but not this

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="slides">
 <img class="item-1 cardone" src="images/cardone.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-2 cardtwo" src="images/cardtwo.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-3 cardthree" src="images/cardthree.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-4 cardfour" src="images/cardfour.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-5 cardfive" src="images/cardfive.jpg"/>
 </div>

<img class="cardone" src="images/cardone.jpg"/><!-- gets added to slides on click, existing image with same class removed at the same time-->

$('.cardone').click(function(){
    var newSrc = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).insertAfter($('.slides img:nth-child(2)')).addClass('item-3');
    $('.slides img').not(this).removeClass(newSrc);
});
```

When cardone gets clicked, it gets added to slides, trying to replace the existing image with the same class name. Farthest I got is to remove the class but not the image itself.

Comment: Given that your inserting the `img` rather than simply changing its `src`, you're find the img to insert after, so you can use the same code to remove that img: `$('.slides img:nth-child(2)').remove();` - is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @ freedomn-m Inserting that particular image at nth-child(2) due to placement on my carousel. Problem is I need to remove the same image with the same src attribute. I've tried to change the src so the image basically will disappear but was having problem with that as well.   If you can change the src by all means that would work as well

Comment: You can pass event as a parameter and than below line of code might can help:  $(event.target).not(this).removeClass(newSrc);

Comment: But I still have question you want to append cardone as image 3?

Comment: @Nimmi   that is correct, by doing that replacing the same card in the stack at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
 $("."+newSrc+"").not(this).remove();
```

Example:-

```js
$('.cardone').click(function(){
    var newSrc = $(this).attr('class');
    $("."+newSrc+"").not(this).remove();
    $(this).insertAfter($('.slides img:nth-child(2)')).addClass('item-3');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides">
 <img class="item-1 cardone" src="images/cardone.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-2 cardtwo" src="images/cardtwo.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-3 cardthree" src="images/cardthree.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-4 cardfour" src="images/cardfour.jpg"/>
 <img class="item-5 cardfive" src="images/cardfive.jpg"/>
 </div>

<img class="cardone" src="images/cardone.jpg"/> // gets added to slides on click, existing image with same class removed at the same time.
```

Comment: I was thinking by removing the src would remove the image element but it doesn't because the class "item-1" is attached to it. I suppose I need the img totally removed and not just the src. But you did exactly how I thought I needed it.

Comment: @BradVanderbush  check now

Comment: Brilliant! That works as well. The code before this one I broke apart and made it work as well. $("."+newSrc+"").not(this).remove('img');   helped a lot.

Comment: @BradVanderbush  glad to help you